# How do I get rid of two lockscreens?

Tags: lock-screens, ads, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have a Samsung Note 8. I took my phone to the store yesterday, and now I have a second lock screen with ads. I have gone through all of my apps that I dont regularly use, and have tried cleaning up junk files off of my phone, but nothing has worked. Does anyone know a way to get rid of this screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That lock screen (the one with ads) is usually from a cleaner app like clean master, 360, baidu etc there should be an On and Off switch inside the app or you can just uninstall the app
If you couldn't find it tell me the name of the app i tell you where it is